# Display content if i'm in the post

Tags: wordpress

I hope i will be clear with my explaination . Is it possible to show for exemple a simple text if the user is in the post . 
For instance, i show in my case a simple text if the user is in the template category, but i want to display also this text if the user is in the content of the post :

I need with a function because it's in the header.php file .

With this function, i can show the simple text "Hello World" if i'm on http://mywebsite.com/category/ and what about http://mywebsite.com/the-name-of-the-post ?

```
<?php if (basename($template) == "category.php")  
{
echo 'Hello World';
}
?>
```

Thanks guys, i hope it's clear (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WordPress Conditional Tags:

```
if ( is_single() || is_page() ) ) {  
// If it's a single post or a single page echo 'Hello Single!'
echo 'Hello Single!';
}
if ( is_archive() && is_category() ) {
    // If it's an archive page for any category, echo 'Hello Category!"
echo 'Hello Category!';
}
```

Read more about [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) on the WordPress Codex.